# How to select id and name of multiselect input control in jrxml?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am working with jasperserver and ireport. I have created multiselect input control. I need to access its id as well as name in report. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

The value gets passed as the value of the relevant parameter (the parameter with exactly the same name as the input control). The label used in the input control (if any) does not get passed to the report. It's it's something that you want to pass to the report then you need to pass it as part of the value.